# Need help creating a column based on calculations on three other columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data file like this:

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|01",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|02", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|03",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|04", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|05",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|06", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|07",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|08", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|09",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|10", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|11",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|12", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|13",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|14", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|15",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|16", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|17",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|18", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|19",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|20", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|21",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|22", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|23",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|24", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|25",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|26", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|27",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|28", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|29",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|30", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|31",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|32"), class = "factor"), t = c(60,
120, 180, 240, 300, 360), activity = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), moving = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), asleep = c(TRUE,
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = c("behavr", "data.table", "data.frame"), sorted = "id", .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000019c94541ef0>, metadata = structure(list(
id = structure(1L, .Label = c("2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|01",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|02", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|03",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|04", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|05",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|06", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|07",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|08", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|09",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|10", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|11",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|12", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|13",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|14", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|15",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|16", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|17",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|18", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|19",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|20", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|21",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|22", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|23",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|24", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|25",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|26", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|27",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|28", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|29",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|30", "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|31",
"2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt|32"), class = "factor"),
file_info = list(list(path = "C:/Users/ariji/Desktop/ShinyWrapperForCircadianAnalysis/Monitor1.txt",
file = "Monitor1.txt")), region_id = 1L, experiment_id = "2020-07-26 00:00:00|Monitor1.txt",
start_datetime = structure(1595721600, class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), stop_datetime = structure(1596326400, class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), genotype = "Early", replicate = 1L,
uid = 1L), sorted = "id", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000019c94541ef0>))
```

Full file here -  https://anonymousfiles.io/1vypEs9u/ (read in with `fread`).
What I need to do is - make another column to this data.table called `noramct`. The values in `noramct` should be (`activity`/sum of all `activity` for that day (1,2,3...7). This has to be done by each individual by the column `id`. So basically, for every `id`, I want a *normalized activity* (that particular `id`'s `activity` divided by that particular day's activity of that particular `id`). Remember the sum of one day's activity has two levels, all `activity` from one particular id and one particular `day`, it may be confusing because one day's `activity` will have counts from multiple `id`s.
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in anticipation.
Question has been asked in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/leff15/need_help_creating_a_column_based_on_calculations/) also.

Comment: Maybe with dplyr, `df %>% group_by(day, id) %>% mutate(noramct = activity / sum(activity)`? Otherwise could you make [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a simplified dataset? That data is extremely complicated.

Comment: Thank you @JoeRoe , it solves the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but I think it suffices to first create the denominator for each observation (I understand it is the total activity of its corresponding id and day), and then simply divide each value by its corresponding denominator. Luckily, this is quite straightforward in data.table:

```
data[, day_activity_for_id := sum(activity), by = .(id, day)
   ][, noramct := activity/day_activity_for_id]
```

Also, friendly advice for next time: it is much easier to understand your problem if you show us a print of the head of the table, not it's cumbersome structure!
data.table prints it quite cleanly in your console

```
head(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @pheymanss , it solves the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [mrmogel](https://www.reddit.com/user/mrmogel/) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/lefgls/need_help_creating_a_column_based_on_calculations/gmf7soq/?context=3) which solved my question first:

You can do this in many ways, but with `tidyverse` this sounds like a job for `group_by`.

```
myData %>%
  group_by(id, Day) %>%
  mutate(activityNorm = activity/sum(activity)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

What this does is effectively splits your data into groups by `id` and `Day`, and then does the `mutate` by each group. That means the sum will be unique for each id and Day.

Alternatively in `data.table` (note: my `data.table` skills are a little rusty).

```
myData[, activityNorm := activity/sum(activity), by = .(id, Day)]
```